# What is the domain of an operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

There seems to be a lot confusion on this notion of a domain of an operator $D(A)$ where $A$ is an operator.

Can someone use a simple example to illustrate exactly what this is?

Say, let $A$ be a linear operator s.t. $A(ax+y) = aAx + Ay$, then what is the domain of A?

Comment: Not sure what the confusion is. An operator is a mapping between vector spaces (or modules, if you're into that). Other than that, it's hard to say what the domain of a particular operator is without further information.

Comment: The domain you speak of is the same as that for functions. One place the domain of an operator needs to be specified is unbounded self-adjoint operators on a Hilbert space. It is an immediate corollary of the closed graph theorem that any everywhere defined self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space is bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, let $X=L^{2}[0,2\pi]$ and let $A=-\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}$ on the domain $\mathcal{D}(A)$ consisting of all functions $f$ which are continuously differentiable on $[0,2\pi]$ and for which $f'$ is absolutely continuous on $(0,2\pi)$ with $f'' \in L^{2}[0,\pi]$. This is as large a domain as you can reasonable expect for $A$. This operator is not selfadjoint. It's adjoint is the restriction $A_{00}$ of $A$
$$
           \mathcal{D}(A_{00}) = \{ f \in \mathcal{D}(A) | f(0)=f'(0)=0,\;f(2\pi)=f'(2\pi)=0 \}
$$
Neither $A$ nor $A_{00}$ is selfadjoint, but $A_{00}$ is symmetric because $(A_{00}f,g)=(f,A_{00}g)$ for all $f,g \in \mathcal{D}(A_{00})$.

Consider the operator $A_{0}$ which is the restriction of $A$ to
$$
         \mathcal{D}(A_{0}) = \{ f \in \mathcal{D}(A) | f(0)=f(2\pi)=0 \}
$$
This operator is selfadjoint and has a complete orthogonal basis of eigenvectors
$$
            \{ \sin(\frac{1}{2}x),\sin(x),\sin(\frac{3}{2}x)\,\sin(2x),\cdots \}.
$$

Consider the operator $A_{p}$ which is the restriction of $A$ to periodic functions
$$
         \mathcal{D}(A_{p}) = \{ f \in \mathcal{D}(A) | f(0)=f(2\pi),\;f'(0)=f'(2\pi) \}
$$
This operator is also selfadjoint with a complete orthogonal basis of eigenfunctions
$$
          \{ 1,\sin(x),\cos(x),\sin(2x),\cos(2x),\cdots \}.
$$